# How to match a valid property access after $ctrl. using regex in js?

Tags: javascript

I want to find the property after `$ctrl.` and the regex I used to do this: `/\$ctrl\.(\w+)(?:\.\w+)?/g`.

This regex is not good enough because for this input:

```
const str =
  '$ctrl.bla $ctrl.bar.foo $ctrl.bla{{index}}.foo $ctrl.1bla $ctrl.invalid.prop{{index}}';
```

It matched:

```
$ctrl.bla      <--- good.
$ctrl.bar.foo. <-- not good. should find the `bar` because it's the word after $ctrl.
$ctrl.bla      <--- goood
$ctrl.1bla.    <-- invalid property syntax because it has number.
$ctrl.invalid.prop  <-- should match the invalid word not matter that prop end with {{.
```

How to change the regex to match valid property syntax?

```
const regex = /\$ctrl\.(\w+)(?:\.\w+)?/g;
const str =
  '$ctrl.bla $ctrl.bar.foo $ctrl.bla{{index}}.foo $ctrl.1bla $ctrl.invalid.prop{{index}}';
let match;

while ((match = regex.exec(str)) != null) {
  console.log(match[0]);
}
```

[stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-c7w3c3?file=index.ts)

Comment: You mean `/\$ctrl\.[a-zA-Z]+/g` ?

Comment: almost. because it match `$ctrl.bla{{index}}.foo` which I don't because `bla{{index}}` is not valid property syntax.

Comment: It doesn't match it, it just match `$ctrl` literally and then only at least one `a-z` characters case insensitive

Comment: try `'$ctrl.bla $ctrl.bar.foo $ctrl.bla{{index}}.foo $ctrl.1bla $ctrl.invalid.prop{{index}}'.match(/\$ctrl\.[a-zA-Z]+/g)`, it returns `['$ctrl.bla', '$ctrl.bar', '$ctrl.bla', '$ctrl.invalid']`

Comment: `/\$ctrl\.[a-zA-Z]+/g` returns `$ctrl.bla` from `$ctrl.bla{{index}}.foo`. I want to ignore this match because the match should be `bla{{index}}`. but it's not a valid property syntax. is possible to do?

Comment: `/\$ctrl\.[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|\.|$)/g` i just added a positive lookahead to assert that a valid prop will end with spaces or a point or the end of the string

Comment: Yes. This is the answer. please post it as the answer to this question. but why it returning the `$ctrl.` in the results? is it possible to not include this in the regex? or I must use `map` to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously posted in comments you can use a regex to match only letters (`a-zA-Z` to make only the prop case insensitive) and lookahead/lookbehind to match only what you need.

My solution:

```js
const regex = /(?<=\$ctrl\.)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|\.|$)/g

console.log('$ctrl.bla $ctrl.bar.foo $ctrl.bla{{index}}.foo $ctrl.1bla $ctrl.invalid.prop{{index}}'.match(regex))
// Output: ['bla', 'bar', 'invalid']
```

Regex explained:

- `(?<=\$ctrl\.)`: This is a positive lookbehind because i need to match only properties that follows `$ctrl` without actually matching it
- `[a-zA-Z]+`: this match only letters from `a` to `z` case insensitive (`+` is to match at least one of them)
- `(?=\s|\.|$)`: This is a positive lookahead and i use it to assert that if i match a prop the actual string will end after it either by having spaces (`\s`), points (`\.`) or becase the string ends (`$`)

By using lookbehind and lookahead we're sure of matching only what we need (in this case only the prop name)